# Before I'm up(before it's my turn, it'll be your turn next(you're up next)

Tags: word-usage, american-english

A person is waiting outside a shop in a queue(a very famous shop) get the famous shop to get the world famous sweets. So he says:

> 1.They shouldn't run out of sweets before I'm up.
>
> 2.They shouldn't run out of sweets before it's my turn.

What sounds better **option 2** or **option 2**?

And what about other contexts:

> I'm up next.
>   It's my turn next.
>
> > When am I up?(or when are you up?)
> >     When is it  my turn?(or when is it your turn?)
> >
> > > It's your turn.
> > >       You're up now.

Answer (score 2):

You use the word *queue* so I imagine you are asking about British English, not American - they would say *line*.

Normally we say, "I'm up next" to refer to a formal performance or hearing.

**Examples**

He is up next before the judge on a charge of theft.

She is up next in the auditions for the new musical.

John is up next to receive his graduation certificate.

---

When you are talking about a queue you should always say,  *it's my turn*.

Comment: And what about these sentences:   
     **1.They shouldn't run out of sweets 
       before I'm up.**
        
        **2.They shouldn't run out of 
           sweets before it's my turn.**

Comment: Can you please help me? @chasly from UK

Comment: The answer appears to address that - you just have to apply what it says to your question.